# Send an Array with Ajax and receive it in ASP Classic page

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, asp-classic

I need to pass an array with AJAX in a ASP page.
I tried passing it as GET to see the data that it sends and i noticed that the ASP receive only the LAST record of the array.
How can i send and receive the whole array? (preferably with POST method)

**Javascript**

```
function editar(i) {
    arr=[];
    j=0;
    for (n=2; n<=9; n++) {
        arr[j]=$("#"+i+"-"+n).val(); //saves in the array all the field of a table's row
    }
    $.ajax ({
        url:"page.asp",
        data: { arr:arr },
        type:"POST"
    }).done(function(msg){
        alert(msg)
    })
}
```

**ASP page.asp**

```
<%  
    redim arr(10)
    for i=0 to 9
        arr(i)=request.Form("arr[]") 'Tried without the square brackets too
    next
%>
```

Comment: can you use jscript instead of vbscript? then you can use the json2.js lib, or if it's internal-use-only, eval(). it's always nice to have an isomorphic code base as well.

Comment: @dandavis i can't, i need to do this with vbscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An html form doesn't have an array data structure. In fact, an html form doesn't really have data types: pretty much everything you put into a form will come back out as a string. So your best bet is probably to write the array into a string (via `.join()`), which you can then parse on the other end (using, e.g. `Split()`).

Keeping in mind that I'm terrible at JavaScript, I think you'd do something like

```js
data: { 'arr':arr.join('+++') }
```

and then in your VBScript, you'd do

```vbs
dim arr '- note that you're NOT dimming as an array
arr = Split(Request.Form("arr"),"+++")
```

<sub>Note that in practice, whenever I use Split, I add a delimiter to the end, just to make sure that Split won't throw an error.</sub>

```vbs
const delimiter = "+++"
arr = Split(Request.Form("arr") & delimiter,delimiter)
```

Comment: That's right! In fact that is what i've done. It works perfecly. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

```
function editar(i) {
arr=[];
j=0;
for (n=2; n<=9; n++) {
    arr[j]=$("#"+i+"-"+n).val(); //saves in the array all the field of a table's row
}
$.ajax ({
    url:"page.asp",
    data: { 'arr[]':arr },
    type:"POST"
}).done(function(msg){
    alert(msg)
})
```

}

i had to change your "arr" in the data object to 'arr[]' and that will do

use the snippet below on the server side
C#

```
    string[] values = Request.Form.GetValues("arr[]");
```

Vb

```
Dim values As String() = Request.Form.GetValues("arr[]");
```

Comment: The ASP still receives only the last record

Comment: Victor, note that the OP is using asp-classic, so neither C# nor VB are relevant.